# Is my Canon camera broken?

Tags: camera

I haven't used my camera for a while, so I charged my battery and once it went green I put it in my camera and it won't turn on but when I press the button to take a photo I can hear the lens moving. When I put the battery back into the charger it says it is flat. Is my camera broken or do I just need a new battery? I don't want to buy a new battery if it isn't going to work!

Comment: What is your camera? How old is it? Is this the original battery that came with the camera?

Comment: Rechargeable batteries have a limited life span. Eventually they will not take as much of  a charge as they once did. Even later, they won't take enough of a charge to power whatever it is they were made for.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It won't turn on?" The screen does not light up? (that could be due to a screen display setting.) Do any of the lights inside the optical viewfinder light up when you half press the shutter button? What happens when you press the 'Menu' button?

Comment: Can you bring it to a camera shop and ask a friendly salesperson to try a different battery in your camera?

Comment: Common problem with old cameras, and even more with speedlites, that haven't been used for a while: The batteries went green indeed! :)

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that you have a bad battery.

Answer (score 3):

Very likely a battery problem. Li-ion batteries [don't like to be fully discharged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164103/if-li-ion-battery-is-deeply-discharged-is-it-harmful-for-it-to-remain-in-this-s). You can find not-so-expensive replacement batteries (no need for Canon brand ones, but check what the users say on Amazon or such sites).

You can also try to [revive the battery yourself](https://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/low_voltage_cut_off) or find someone to do it for you.

Comment: Messing with Lithium Ion batteries in such manner can turn them into a safety hazard for you and others. At the very least, read the warnings in that article about what constitutes trying too hard - and if you ignore them, *clearly label the battery as experimental and potentially unsafe*.